# Stuck on the last step of Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, mac, macbook

I've just tried installing ubuntu on my 2008 MacBook Pro 2.5ghz intel core 2 duo (from a USB thumb drive) - to replace my Mac OS entirely. I've followed all the steps successfully (I'm assuming) but when it comes to rebooting after install, I get stuck on the reboot page asking me to remove medium and press enter. Removing the stick and pressing enter does nothing. If I then manually switch off the mac, and restart it, I get stuck on the purple screen. I have tried to reinstall a few times to no avail. I have also read that a potential solution is to reboot --> GRUB --> recovery but I can only get to GRUB by reinserting my USB stick, and there is no option for recovery mode. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with last Ubuntus, I think you need repair your grub. For this is simplest way to use existing live-CD/USB-stick and [follow these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

It is a bit tedious, but has worked for me.